# Disable previous dates in datepicker odoo 10

Tags: date, datepicker, odoo, restrict

I am trying to disable the previous dates at payment of invoice but it doesnt work for me.

Here is my model:

```
from odoo import models, fields, api
from datetime import datetime
from openerp.tools import DEFAULT_SERVER_DATE_FORMAT


class account_payment(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'account.payment'

    def onchange_date(self, cr, uid, ids, payment_date, context=None):
        if datetime.strptime(payment_date, DEFAULT_SERVER_DATE_FORMAT).date() > datetime.now().date():
            return False
        return payment_date
```

Here is my xml file:

```
<odoo>
  <data>

        <record model="ir.ui.view" id="view_account_payment_invoice_form">

            <field name="name">account.payment.invoice.form</field>

            <field name="model">account.payment</field>

            <field name="inherit_id" ref="account.view_account_payment_invoice_form"/>

            <field name="arch" type="xml">

                <xpath expr="//field[@name='payment_date']" position="replace">

                    <field name="payment_date" on_change="onchange_date(payment_date)"/>

                </xpath>

            </field>

        </record>


  </data>
</odoo>
```

Error:

TypeError: onchange_date() takes at least 5 arguments (2 given)

Please could somebody help me. Thanks!

Comment: You can do this by using api decorator. This link may help you.

[Model constraints](http://odoo-development.readthedocs.io/en/latest/dev/py/constraints.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this might be useful, 
Your model:

```
@api.onchange('payment_date')
def onchange_date(self):
    if datetime.strptime(self.payment_date, DEFAULT_SERVER_DATE_FORMAT).date() > datetime.now().date():
        self.payment_date = ''
```

Your view:

```
<odoo>
  <data>
        <record model="ir.ui.view" id="view_account_payment_invoice_form">
            <field name="name">account.payment.invoice.form</field>
            <field name="model">account.payment</field>
            <field name="inherit_id" ref="account.view_account_payment_invoice_form"/>
            <field name="arch" type="xml">
                <xpath expr="//field[@name='payment_date']" position="replace">
                    <field name="payment_date"/>
                </xpath>
            </field>
        </record>
  </data>
</odoo>
```

Comment: Thanks Suhindra and thanks to all for your replies. This worked for me. And sorry for late reply.

Comment: Help me, i have problem. The problem is disable holiday in datepicker. How to solve?

Comment: @С.Дэлгэрцэцэг   why not post your question?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51666451/disable-holiday-dates-in-datepicker-odoo-10 Please, check this post. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are getting an error is because you are mixing the old and new API. If you want to use the old style API (`cr, uid, ids, ...` and the XML `on_change=...`) then you must add a decorator onto your new API method (your python is new API since your class inherits `models.Model`).

#### models/account_payment.py

```
# This decorator provides cr, uid, ids, and context variables
# to your method by default (like the old API had)
@api.cr_uid_ids_context
def onchange_date(self, cr, uid, ids, payment_date, context=None):
    ...
```

You can read more about some of these special decorators (which were introduced in version 9.0) on [this blog post](https://www.surekhatech.com/blog/new-api-for-odoo-v9)