# Disable holiday dates in datepicker odoo 10

Tags: datetime, datetimepicker, odoo

if selected day is holiday disable mouse. It's possible in odoo datetime field. /datetimepicker/. 
Any help will be appreciated.

Note:Disable previous dates in datepicker odoo 10/ backend/

Comment: the field is : <field name="delivery_deadline"/> and .py is delivery_deadline = fields.Datetime('Delivery Date')

Comment: Note:  I have little solution, but can't do it. Create new custom widget.  Help